# Conflict with config class in dependency (Spring AsyncConfig)

Tags: spring, maven, spring-async

My team uses some starter code that's included in every internal Spring project by default.  This is included as a dependency (not parent) in the pom.xml file of my project.  This starter code contains a default implementation of a configuration interface which Spring does not allow duplicates of (AsyncConfigurer), but I need to create my own custom implementation.  I am not sure how to resolve this.  Is there a way for me to exclude this configuration class but keep the rest of the dependency? Or can I somehow keep the given config class, but modify its properties?

The specific exception I get is: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one AsyncConfigurer may exist`

//Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can define the AsyncConfigurer on parameter excludes from @SpringBootApplication. Example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=AsyncConfigurer.class)
```

Notice that this will excludes the entire @Configuration .
Another solution is to use bean override, to define only the beans you need to replace.
Add this to your application.properties (or yaml):

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

And you will be able to override it.